# Django Static Files 404 even when findstatic found the files

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a web using django, and whenever i moved to another machine I always get 404 error on my static files.

I tried using findstatic command and it says it found my static files, but it still won't load on my site

```
    python manage.py findstatic css/base.css
    Found 'css/base.css' here:
    /home/aoki/Project/Menulis/code/static/css/base.css
```

I've also tried using collect static and STATIC_ROOT setting, it just won't work

Here is my settings.py

```py
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/'),
)
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

here is the log

```
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6373
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/images/graphics/dev.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/images/graphics/dev.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
[25/May/2019 03:17:51] "GET /static/js/sw.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1037
```

Thanks

Comment: A couple of things here: 1) Remove trailing slash from `static/` in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')`. 2) If you inspect your page source in browser dev tools, what URLs are called for fetching static resources?

Comment: thanks, but it seemed didn't work 1)I've done it, 2) it href from static/css/base.css

Comment: if you're using runserver then you might need to include `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`